# Please suggest correct way to unit test both functions using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

How to unit test for maximum coverage ? should i add try catch block so i can check for failures ?

```js
var d = new Date();
month = getCurrentMonth(d);
day = getCurrentDay(d);

function getCurrentMonth(d) {
  a = d.getMonth() + 1;
  return (a < 10) ? '0' + a.toString() : a.toString();
}

function getCurrentDay(d) {
  b = d.getDate() - 1;
  return (b < 10) ? '0' + b.toString() : b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have small bug in getCurrentDay func, you don't need to substract 1.

Here i written all needed tests, do you have any questions?
The most important thing is that you should provide const dates for tests. Not static dates can change over time. (for example you shouldn't use new Date() without parameter)

```js
function getCurrentMonth(d){
  a=d.getMonth()+1;
  return (a< 10) ? '0' + a.toString() : a.toString();
}

function getCurrentDay(d){
  b=d.getDate();
  return (b< 10) ? '0' + b.toString() : b.toString();
}

test('should add 0 before month if contains 1 number', () => {
  let d = new Date('2020-01-01T10:10:00Z')
  expect(getCurrentMonth(d)).toBe("01");
});

test('should return month', () => {
  let d = new Date('2020-10-01T10:10:00Z')
  expect(getCurrentMonth(d)).toBe("10");
});

test('should add 0 before day if contains 1 number', () => {
  let d = new Date('2020-01-02T10:10:00Z')
  expect(getCurrentDay(d)).toBe("02");
});

test('should return day', () => {
  let d = new Date('2020-10-21T10:10:00Z')
  expect(getCurrentDay(d)).toBe("21");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Focus on `(a < 10) ? ...` condition to write unit tests. Don't need to add try catch block to the function, let it throws error when `d` is not an instance of `Date`. Use `expect().toThrow()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can see there 2 functions, every one have 1 conditional statements, so for achieving maximum branch coverage you'll need at least 4 calls.

Also, the only error you can make there is when the parameter is not a data instance. In your example you are not validating the input data so it is not really part of your function, it is more like undefined behaviour.

Check both of your functions for both of if-cases - for example in getCurrentMonth when a is less than 10 and when a is equal or more than 10. This will get you 100% branch coverage so far.